# How to serialize complex List of data?

Tags: c#, serialization

I need to serialize a complex `List<List<byte[]>>`.

I tried usual XML Serialization and got proper XML file with `ArrayOfArrayOfBase64Binary` complex element inside. But while deserialization I got exception -
`System.InvalidOperationException: <ArrayOfArrayOfBase64Binary xmlns=''> didn't expected`

This is the obtained XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfArrayOfBase64Binary xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ArrayOfBase64Binary>
    <base64Binary>uWmpcJ5NsuN+kDdc7LHKeAQDRpt9tww2eQejjw==</base64Binary>
    <base64Binary>wkHfOzURrWoibj6ayvvLvP/MC69zitU/8/rC3A==</base64Binary>
    <base64Binary>io4VUpcqK0wjGx29KEUtaoB0mM4ezVVPCwwiVQ==</base64Binary>
    .... 
    <base64Binary>VB7qwOVZVzqIP2aDvEd5BqPmseMvDDt+6jJC2A==</base64Binary>
    <base64Binary>bBH7CSP0e2zEDBTpOjqEPXZS5GhQ+21Aa6L9sQ==</base64Binary>
    <base64Binary>g3CKGhBT9oJHn3xJCAtFL9bM+7IJCPXdJIqysg==</base64Binary>
    <base64Binary>4o+aIxOu9xZ1EX/+KvaifPjyDNhBgtPZshbjUg==</base64Binary>
    </ArrayOfBase64Binary>
  <ArrayOfBase64Binary>
    <base64Binary>4h92Duu+R8UH9seJpmDoboVVOk6YOy8GV0eCtw==</base64Binary>
    <base64Binary>Oe2g/IRc5NbYZqmB/zNEx5V4kelnDpy3rjrrwg==</base64Binary>
    <base64Binary>YMtYeQ3izUkQGrybfVWIzaTpVOvS0ItRN+/I4Q==</base64Binary>
    ....
    <base64Binary>K1cYC737a7vqLvyJtq3JcR06w3ih6c2s+Ocq+g==</base64Binary>
    <base64Binary>4Gc/Em29D2GZ0vm65gg65fypYficzNvG9wNvTQ==</base64Binary>
    <base64Binary>SEHpodvPphyyJlLqoMM2sTWWKnJ9yDz+JkUwCQ==</base64Binary>
    <base64Binary>NS5+EwbsGPOMQlkQvg8lllNi/9vaA6SxnX0nUw==</base64Binary>
  </ArrayOfBase64Binary>
</ArrayOfArrayOfBase64Binary>`
```

And code for serialization/deserialization:

```
//Serialize
using (var stream = File.Create("Levin/RandomData/Z.xml"))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<List<byte[]>>));
    serializer.Serialize(stream, _Z_ext);
}

//Deserialize
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("Levin/RandomData/Z.xml"))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<List<byte[]>>));
    _Z_ext = (List<List<byte[]>>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the xml content and the source code (at least the class you try to deserialize to?)

Comment: Have a look at [mcve]. Include your code, some sample data and xml.

Comment: And the class? If you try to deserialize the xml you get by serializing the class instance, it should work. Do you modify the xml anyhow?

Comment: Of course, No. I didn't change XML

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/KOE2aC  Can you create a [minimal but complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: This xml deserializes fine. There is something that you are hiding from us. You either modify the xml or getting it from somewhere else. The code is working and the xml is fine.

Comment: There are different XML serializers. Where is the code how you call it for serialization and deserialization?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use smth instead of xml:

Serialization:

```
    var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    var fileStream = File.Create(fileName);
    binFormatter.Serialize(fileStream, yourListOfLists);
    fileStream.Close();
```

and to deserialize:

```
    var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    var fileStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open);
    var yourListOfLists = (List<List<byte[]>>)binFormatter.Deserialize(fileStream);
    fileStream.Close();
```

Comment: This is also faster than xml, but disadvantages are that you cannot alter the content of the binary file.

Comment: Of course, but it's easy to alter the content programmatically

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked fine. May be it depends on your data. Please try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<List<byte[]>> _Z_ext = new List<List<byte[]>>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LoadB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("Z.xml"))
        {
            var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<List<byte[]>>));
            _Z_ext = (List<List<byte[]>>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }

    private void SaveB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create some data
        byte[] b1 = new byte[2] { 64, 65 };
        List<byte[]> l1 = new List<byte[]>();
        l1.Add(b1);
        _Z_ext.Add(l1);

        byte[] b2 = new byte[2] { 66, 67 };
        List<byte[]> l2 = new List<byte[]>();
        l2.Add(b2);
        _Z_ext.Add(l2);

        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create("Z.xml"))
        {
            var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<List<byte[]>>));
            serializer.Serialize(stream, _Z_ext);
        }
    }
}
```

Does it work? What if you use your data?